# ui-router child view of an angularjs component not showing

Tags: angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router, angularjs-components, nested-views

I have an angularjs component(almost empty markup) acting as a shell/parent to its child views(markups with different columns/formats).  I am able to see the component but no child views are loaded.

ui-router config code:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {


$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider
  .state('parent', {
    url: '',
    views: {
      'parentComponent': {
        component: 'parentComponent'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('parent.child', {
    url: '/child',
    templateUrl: 'child.html'
  });
```

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="app" >
 <div ng-controller='RoutingCtrl'>
   <parent-component></parent-component>
 </div>
</body>
```

The parent, which is a component:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div>I am the parent, a angularjs component.</div>
    <div>There sould be the nested/child view right below:</div>
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

child:

```
<div>Hi! I am the child!</div>
```

My controller tells ui-router to go to child view:

```
$state.go('parent.child');
```

I don't want to declare parent as abstract because, in my real app, I have views parallel to the parent component view(together, they form a multiple named view) here and these other high level views(except the parent component) must be visible regardless of the child views.

I am using angularjs 1.5.8 and ui-router version 0.4.2

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/tBhVTjttMagaJzHQNvro?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any details what you are trying to accomplish, so based on what it looks right now, you have two options: either go with the `ui-view` template throughout your app and use the parent-child relationship of `ui-router` or go with hybrid approach of loading your component, and inside it, a state you want to show.

- [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/2WO7OH8oDOpOlH672tbb?p=preview) with parent-child relationship - This example uses `ui-view` throughout the app. `parent-component` is loaded with it's own state and it's not `abstract`. This approach is good if you want to load different templates for different states in the same place.
- [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hxf3U5douViMbbo4CrvF?p=preview) with hybrid approach. This example follows your current app structure with `parent-component` loaded in `index.html` and a state loaded in your `parent-component`. You can see that you really don't need a `parent` state here as you have put your `parent-component` directly in `index.html` file. State `child` is loaded in inside your `parent-component` and it doesn't need a parent state.

Comment: Really appreciate your excellent answers, eminlala!! Here are more details of what I am trying to accomplish: .the purpose of the component part is to show search results whose input comes from different parts of the index.html pages.  I made sure the input is in the parent scope of the component.  The input parameters can be different so the columns/format of data shown in the component are also different. Another important requirement is that the component must also be able to use url paramters (using $stateparams).  I still don't understand why my plunker is not working.

Comment: No problem :), if this helps you in any way, you can up vote it. The Plunker link you provided had an error when defining the `parent.child` state. Either just erase the `views:` part or add it like you did for the `parent` state.

Comment: I really wanted to vote it but not eligible.  Stackoverflow requires at least 15 reputations in order to vote